# Is COT (cost of transfer) exsists in bank from a certain country to another? (Eg. Uk to philippines or othe country to philippines)

Tags: banking, financial-literacy, bank-account, online-banking, cryptocurrency

Heres the scenario: I have invested through bitcoin to a certain company but the thing is endless payments were being asked and i have complied with them. A few days i received from a certain bank named hpsbank(i dont even know where it is located) asking me for a COT (cost of transfer) of $3500. The account was on my name and they gave me my account name and my password. I was a bit hesitant because their website seemed to be legit but the cons was they dont have a contact number and ive googled about it they are not registered with BBB and FDIC. Now here are my questions i hope you can help me shed light on this.

Questions:

1. Is there really what they called a cost of tranfer between international banks?
2. If ever these are not legit, where can i possible file a complaint to get my money back?

Thank you.

Comment: This is why I stick with national fiat money.

Comment: The phrase "cost of transfer" is 99% associated with fraud or scam.

Comment: Yeah sure did, thank you base64. By any chance do you know how can i file a complaint about it or where can i possibly file complaint regarding fraud from these companies?